# Reading a multiline text file using sscanf and fgets

Tags: c, text, struct, fgets, scanf

I need to read a text file, and then print the results out. I am using a struct to hold the variables, and I do not need to create an array. The problem is that the code seems to either not be reading the second line or I'm printing incorrectly, and the results are completely jumbled. Here is the text file:

```
UTSA01 8 0 150.00 80.00
Armadillos,utsa@xyz.com,(210)555-1111,Jean E Us 
COM001 7 1 150.00 75.00
Comm Eagles,maeking@xyz.com,(210)555-2222,Mae King
SOUTH1 5 3 120.00 75.00
Slam Dunk,slamdunk@gmail.com,(210)555-3333,Jerry Tall
ALHGHT 4 4 175.00 100.00
Cake Eaters,sliverspoon@xyz.com,(210)555-6666,E Z Street
UNKN01 1 7 150.00 50.00 
Org New Blk,bobwire@xyz.com,(210)555-1234,Bob Wire
NEWB01 0 8 120.00 75.00
River Rats,riverrat@xyz.com,(210)555-4444,Rock D Boat
UNKN02 3 5 150.00 75.00
Hackers,cyber@gmail.com,(210)555-5555,Tom E Gunn
```

I've been using sscanf and fgets in a while loop. Here is my code:

```
char szInputBuffer[100];
/* Create a struct array that will hold the data that is being read in */
Team teams;

/* The following segment contains the header for the file */
printf("%-7s%-13sWins Loss Fee Amt  Paid Amt\n", "Id", "Team Name");
printf("                %-21s%-14sEmail\n", "Contact Name", "Phone");

/* The following structure will begin to read file data into the respectful 
   variables until the end-of-file marker has been reached.
   The data will be used later to print out. */

while(!feof(pFileTeam)) {
    fgets(szInputBuffer, 100, pFileTeam);
    sscanf(szInputBuffer, "%7s %d %d %lf %lf",
                           teams.szTeamId,
                           &teams.iWins,
                           &teams.iLosses,
                           &teams.dFeeAmount,
                           &teams.dPaidAmount);

    fgets(szInputBuffer, 256, pFileTeam);                      
    sscanf(szInputBuffer, "%[^,]%[^,]%[^,]%[^\n]",
           teams.szTeamName,
           teams.szEmailAddr,
           teams.szPhone,
           teams.szContactname);


    printf("%-7s%-13s%-5d%-5d%-9.2lf%-8.2lf\n",
        teams.szTeamId,
        teams.szTeamName,
        teams.iWins,
        teams.iLosses,
        teams.dFeeAmount,
        teams.dPaidAmount);
    printf("                %-21s%-14s%-5s\n",
        teams.szContactname,
        teams.szPhone,
        teams.szEmailAddr);
}//END while
```

The problem I am having is that I can read and print the first line of the file, long with the first string in the second line. However, it seems to get tripped up once I hit the comma. I'm not sure if it is the specifiers that I am using in the sscanf or if it is printing. I am really confused as to what I should do.

Here are my results when I compile (gcc) and execute:

```
Id     Team Name    Wins Loss  Fee Amt   Paid Amt
                    Contact Name         Phone         Email
    UTSA01 Armadillos      8    0    150.00     80.00

    COM001 Comm Eagles     7    1    150.00     75.00

    SOUTH1 Slam Dunk       5    3    120.00     75.00

    ALHGHT Cake Eaters     4    4    175.00    100.00

    UNKN01 Org New Blk     1    7    150.00     50.00

    NEWB01 River Rats      0    8    120.00     75.00

    UNKN02 Hackers         3    5    150.00     75.00
```

It actually showed some strange characters on the second lines in my terminal, but they don't seem to show up on here.

EDIT: I've added the commas, but the output is still not working. Only the last printed line will show the szContactname information. All of the other ones leave that spot blank, but the phone and email are shown:

```
Id     Team Name    Wins Loss  Fee Amt   Paid Amt
                    Contact Name         Phone         Email
    UTSA01 Armadillos      8    0    150.00     80.00
                    (210)555-1111 utsa@xyz.com
    COM001 Comm Eagles     7    1    150.00     75.00
                    (210)555-2222 maeking@xyz.com
    SOUTH1 Slam Dunk       5    3    120.00     75.00
                    (210)555-3333 slamdunk@gmail.com
    ALHGHT Cake Eaters     4    4    175.00    100.00
                    (210)555-6666 sliverspoon@xyz.com
    UNKN01 Org New Blk     1    7    150.00     50.00
                    (210)555-1234 bobwire@xyz.com
    NEWB01 River Rats      0    8    120.00     75.00
                    (210)555-4444 riverrat@xyz.com
    UNKN02 Hackers         3    5    150.00     75.00
                    Tom E Gunn           (210)555-5555 cyber@gmail.com
```

Comment: You probably have other problems as well but for starters: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: I added the commas, but the last line is the only one that is correct. The other lines all print the phone number and email, but no contact name. The last line, however, prints the contact name, phone, and email all in correct formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Some problems

1. Using the `fgets()` buffer without checking the result.  Check the result of `fgets()` before attempting to use `szInputBuffer`.  Further `feof()` check not needed. [@kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682024/reading-a-multiline-text-file-using-sscanf-and-fgets#comment66664172_39682024)

   ```
   // while(!feof(pFileTeam)) {
   //    fgets(szInputBuffer, 100, pFileTeam);
   //    sscanf(szInputBuffer, ....
   while(fgets(szInputBuffer, sizeof szInputBuffer, pFileTeam) != NULL) {
       sscanf(szInputBuffer, ....
   ```
2. Using magic numbers.  Think about 256.  `szInputBuffer[]` is not that big.

   ```
   char szInputBuffer[100];
   ...  
   // fgets(szInputBuffer, 256, pFileTeam);   
   if (fgets(szInputBuffer, sizeof szInputBuffer, pFileTeam) == NULL) break;
   ```
3. Useless format.  `"%[^,]%[^,]..."` attempts to read text up to a `','` and the *leaves* that `','` in the file stream without reading it.  [@user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682024/reading-a-multiline-text-file-using-sscanf-and-fgets#comment66664193_39682024).  Robust code limits string input and checks `sscanf()` results.

   ```
   // sscanf(szInputBuffer, "%[^,]%[^,]%[^,]%[^\n]", teams.szTeamName, ...
   // Assuming szTeamName[10]
   if (4 != sscanf(szInputBuffer, "%9[^,],%9[^,],%9[^,],%9[^\n]", teams.szTeamName, ...) {
     break;
   }
   ```
4. Maybe others issues.

Comment: Okay, so I used your suggestions, and it still runs the same as before. I understand what you are saying, and it is really helpful. However, I am the results are still confusing me, because I don't understand how the check on sscanf can resolve to 4, and still not contain data for one variable.  What makes it even more confusing is that the variable is blank for the first 6 sets, but the last set contains the information.

Comment: So I changed the regex that controls the newline and just used one that would accept characters and whitespaces - I know that this is not ideal - and it worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, it really helped a ton!